# Removing double quotes for items in list

Tags: python, string, list

```
>>> s = "name='smith'"
>>> s.split('=')
['name', "'smith'"]
```

However, how do I remove the double quotes such that when I do the similiar thing I get:

```
>>> s = "name='smith'"
>>> s.split('=')
['name', 'smith']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x.strip("'") for x in s.split('=')]
```

or

```
s.replace("'","").split("=")
```